# How to refer to file kept under classpath?

Tags: java

In our application, we are sending an email during registration.
For this we have got an email template stored under /usr/local/email.html

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("/usr/local/email.html")),writer);
message.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");
Transport.send(message);
```

**The above is working fine .**

We don't want to hardcode this path (/usr/local/email.html),  wanted to keep under classpath

If I keep it under classpath how can I read it?

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream("email.html");
IOUtils.copy(is,writer);
message.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");
Transport.send(message);
```

With the above code, I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException at

```
IOUtils.copy(is,writer);
```

Comment: Is it in your classpath, at the root level?

Answer (score 0):

If you use getClass().getResourceAsStream with a relative path, the resource is found if it's in the same package as the class.

Alternatively you can use an absolute name like "/some/package/email.html"

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("email.html");
```

Comment: Sorry but Cannot use this in a static context

Answer (score 0):

Your resource is in a fixed, known location on your classpath, so it's best to use the [`Class#getResourceAsStream` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).  You call it on a `Class` object, and it automatically uses the class's `ClassLoader` and looks for the resource in the class's package.

For example, if you have a class called `com.example.myapp.Emailer` and you write:

```
InputStream is = Emailer.class.getResourceAsStream("email.html");
```

it will look for `com/example/myapp/email.html` via the same classloader that's used to load the `Emailer` class.  You'd put `email.html` in your JAR, in the same place as the compiled `Emailer.class` file.

I'd specifically recommend *not* using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for this, because the result can vary from thread to thread, and it could potentially be a classloader that isn't able to access the JAR file that holds your resource.  You want to make sure you're always using the classloader that actually loads your application's classes, and you accomplish that by calling `getResourceAsStream` on the `Class` object of one of your application's classes.